# GCC linker for ARM does not optimize symbol placement

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, ld, compiler-optimization

When I check the memory map after compilation, I can see that the symbols in DATA or BSS section are not ordered in an optimized way, wrt their size and the CPU aligmnent access limitation.

For instance, I am ending up with something like:

```
address  size   name
0x1000      1   var_a
0x1004      4   var_b
0x1008      1   var_c
0x100a      2   var_d
0x100c      4   var_e
0x1010      1   var_f
0x1014      4   var_g
0x1018      0   end
```

instead of getting:

```
0x1000      4   var_b
0x1004      4   var_e
0x1008      4   var_g
0x100c      2   var_d
0x100e      1   var_a
0x100f      1   var_c
0x1010      1   var_f
0x1011      0   end
```

I can see however that all the symbols are mixed up and are not related to their order in the source or during compilation.

I am using the options `-Os` `-flto` `-flto` `-fuse-linker-plugin` `-flto-report` `-flto-compression-level=9`. GCC for ARM is `arm-none-eabi-gcc` v4.8.3 from https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded and `ld` is v2.23.2.

Is there any relevant reason why `ld` is not doing this optimization? How can I reorder the symbols to improve the memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with SORT_BY_ALIGNMENT in the linker script, e.g.:

```
*(SORT_BY_ALIGNMENT(SORT_BY_NAME(.data*)))
```

There is also the following options, though I did not try them:

```
--sort-common [=ascending|descending]
    Sort common symbols by alignment [in specified order]
 --sort-section name|alignment
    Sort sections by name or maximum alignment
```